# How to keep sequence of 1s and 0s in a column on MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, data-structures, type-conversion

I need to store a list of 1s and 0s in a single column on MySQL. For that column max length of the sequence for a cell will be 100.

On java side, after I fetch that data from MySQL, I need to convert it to something like [EvictingQueue](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html) or any other appropriate data type. Because I need to add new values while the earliest entered one (1 or 0) will be popped from the list. Then I will update MySQL with new sequence.

What data type do you suggest me to use on MySQL for that column? Also do you have any other suggestion for Java side? So far, EvictingQueue looks logical to me.

---

**Solution:** I preferred using EvictingQueue on Java side and VARBINARY(100) on MySQL side. Works stable.

Comment: seems rather unusual - whats the purpose of this data

Comment: keeping a record of last 100 boolean values of an operation.   1=true 0=false @amdixon

Comment: what sort of operation ?

Comment: let's say log-in operation. It does not matter. I need to keep a record of last 100 true/false in a cell.

Comment: ok, then you want to structure your table something like a datetime for logintime and a bool  for the login status. bool and boolean are type aliases for tinyint(1)

Comment: no man. I just want to keep a record of 100 login operation whether it is true or false. That is all. No date record or sth else. Just a single cell. Length of 100 sequence of 1s and 0s. @amdixon

Comment: you could use varbinary(100). would have to be sure you understand how youre going to the data afterwards though..

Comment: Don't forget to upvote, downvote, accept any answer. That is our feedback.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, varchar type makes more sense as any numeric type may trim out leading zeros.

For java, I think we can have the value extracted as String and do bitwise shifting as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306647/how-to-bitwise-shift-a-binary-string-in-java).

EvictingQueue is perfectly fine. However, I thought of providing another approach.

Comment: Although I am trying not to any String operation like thing but I'll try. Maybe I have to do something with strings :/  Thank you.